# Bootstrap coloumn with two rows and cols

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is the code i am working on, how can i convert the code into bootstrap grid layout with rows and cols. I want both the volume and storage in a separate row below each other.

Below is image on how it should look.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3>
         <div class="row">
         </div>
         <div class="row">
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have achieved it in css, but i am not sure how to apply bootstrap grid system to it. Below is a fiddle for the same.
http://jsbin.com/tehijapi/4/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well. I believe you want a row consisted of 8 columns. If I get you right, here's how you can achieve that.

You create a wrapper with `.col-xs-X` class depending on how wide you want the inner columns be.

Then you create custom columns with width of 100% devided by **X** *where X is the number of your columns.*

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-4">

          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-1-custom"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-1-custom"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-1-custom"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-1-custom"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-1-custom"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-1-custom"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-1-custom"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-1-custom"></div>

          </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col-xs-1-custom{
    width: 10.5%; /* 100/8 = 12.5% and 2% taken to let margins appear */
    background: green;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

**[Bootply example.](http://www.bootply.com/ikvDzdSY59)**

In your case its 100/8 = 12.5%.But if you want to have space between those columns, you must make the width less so as they don't overflow. In my example I approx. took 2% away to make the margins not overflow.

You can also count the exact number of margin & width for each media query breakpoint. In my case, the `margin` takes 40px out of 293px (`.col-xs-3`) @ 1170px breakpoint, so for your columns the 100% width is not 293px but 293px - 40px.

There's also another way to use the LESS/SASS to customize the `@grid-columns` variable and see how it would look in the recompiled version and simply drag all the settings from there.

Here's **[bootstrap customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)** it will do all the job for you in case you haven't used less/sass.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I have a issue when i implement it here... i want two rows below each other one for storage and other for volume... its not working http://jsbin.com/kugumuwo/1/edit and also when i re-size the cols gets shrinked.

Comment: @theJava Here's I created the column for volume http://www.bootply.com/l8faZPhMnP. Inside the ``col-xs-4`` I created a new row and a ``.col-xs-12``. But changed the width a bit so as it matches the storage. Surely you will have the columns stacked as the viewport decreases. But you asked to do that in a Bootstrap. You may not want to use Bootstrap for such a custom design, because it's easier to create smth from scratch rather than overriding Bootstrap's defaults.